# Is $4/x^{-1}$ a polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Decide whether the expression $4/x^{-1}$ is a polynomial or not.

My idea :

$4/x^{-1}$ = $4x$.   which is clearly a polynomial .

But my colleague said that if we substitute $x=0$ In the expression , we won’t get real value , ie $x=0$ doesn’t belong to Domain of the expression
And hence by the definition of polynomial it will not be a polynomial because it’s domain is not $R$

Looking for more clarification about this question please

Comment: Do you know what $x^{-1}$ means ?

Comment: See [Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial): "an expression consisting of indeterminates (also called variables) and coefficients, that involves only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and **non-negative** integer exponentiation of variables."

Comment: @TheSilverDoe. I fixed typo in post

Comment: It is NOT a polynomial since $0$ does not belong to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated question, because it depends exactly on what you mean by "polynomial." As a **function,** if we consider the functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x)=\frac4{x^{-1}}$$ and $$g(x)=4x,$$ then yes, $f=g.$ As functions, they are equal. However, the functions $f$ and $g$ are not polynomial functions. Why not? Because polynomial functions have $\mathbb{R}$ as their domain.

On the other hand, in mathematics, there is something called a polynomial ring, and in that context, we consider polynomials **formally,** which is to say, not as functions where you can substitute $x$ for a real number, but rather, we treat polynomials on their own terms, and $x$ is just treated as a quantity of its own. In that context $4x$ is a formal polynomial. $1/x$ is a formal **Laurent polynomial,** which, despite the name, is not a polynomial, but a generalization of the concept of a polynomial. Laurent polynomials are like polynomials, but negative exponents are allowed. So, using Laurent polynomial arithmetic, you can come up with an expression such as $4/x^{-1},$ which is equal to $4x$ (since there is no "plugging in" for $x,$ the two quantities are just equal, period). And so, you could say that $4/x^{-1}$ is indeed a polynomial. But, at the same time, you can only write something like $4/x^{-1}$ is you are doing arithmetic with Laurent polynomials, not actual polynomials. So $4/x^{-1}$ really is not a polynomial, it is a Laurent polynomial of degree $1.$ But it is analogous to a polynomial.